# PHP CURL not working on 1&1 server

Tags: php, curl

I have a php page that calls some API for authentication on the same server, but not the same domain, below is the code:

```
    $url = "http://www.mydomain.com/api.php";    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
    curl_close($ch);
```

It was working fine on godaddy, didnt change anything, curl is enabled, when I check the curl_getinfo it returns 404, which is really weird because in the browser its a valid URL, any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to call `curl_errno()` and `curl_error()` and paste output.

Comment: it doesnt return any error, as I mentioned above only getinfo gives 404

Comment: @MihaiIorga it does, just edited the question

Comment: Just an idea - if this is REST API, browser use GET, but in your script you are doing request via POST. Is POST implemented correctly?

Comment: yes I'm positive, its not a REST API, and it was working on another server, thanks

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` must be a valid URL query, maybe adding `http_build_query()` would fix your issue.

Comment: @MihaiIorga: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can be an array.  It just changes the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data` if it is.

Answer (score 2):

cURL init method call is missing. Try this:

```
$url = "www.mydomain.com/api.php";    
$ch= curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Getting 404 means that your request got thru but you're request is invalid ie. you're query isn't well formatted.

Setting CURLOPT_POST to size($_POST) ie true if $_POST is not empty means that your data has to be x-www-form-urlencoded.

This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:

Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by '+', and then 
reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric 
characters are replaced by '%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing 
the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., 
'%0D%0A').

The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is 
separated from the value by '=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by '&'.